# How to specify two index url's and two trusted hosts with pip from command line?

Tags: python, pip

How can I specify two index URL's for pip from command line? And the two indexes I have are http only. So, I need to add `--trusted-host` for them. How can I specify all of this while installing something on the commandline?

Answer (score 0):

With `pip` we can specify two index url' by using the `--index-url` and `--extra-index-url` options in the commandline.

Say, you want to install `pandas`, it would look something like this:

```
pip install --index-url <index-url-1>  --extra-index-url <index-url-2> pandas
```

If an index is not `https` enabled, we need to set the `--trusted-host` option for that index host. If both of the index servers are http based, we can set the `--trusted-host` twice.

```
pip install --trusted-host <index-host-1>  --trusted-host <index-host-2> --index-url <index-url-1>  --extra-index-url <index-url-2> pandas
```

That way, we can install a package from either of the servers.